# Using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make layout like this:

[image]

The problem is with aligning TextViews: I want them both to be centered horizontally. The only solution I've got is to use nested LinearLayout inside root RelativeLayout.
Ho do I center TextViews horizontally **using only the root RelativeLayout, without nested LinearLayout**?

Comment: Can you please post your xml? If you're not too fixed on using the layouts you've mentioned here, I can suggest you to nest a horizontal linear layout inside a vertical linear layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE TRY THIS ::

**Update :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/asdww"
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="new aaaaaa"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

         />


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="new aaaaaa"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Views will be still centered on the right and on the left, but not in the center.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I wanted to know if it was possible to make it without margings.

Comment: there are not more parameter with relative layout so we need to continue with this

Answer (score 4):

Lets say the id 0f `imageview` is image. Then for the 1st `textView` you can do something like this :

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
```

and for the 2nd `textView`,

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
```

You can also give some margin in both the `textViews` after doing this

Answer (score 1):

In your `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

The textviews shall be centered yourself thats of my knowledge. You can implement `android:layout_marginLeft`